# Are there really any production issues in using memcached in Windows?

Tags: memcached

I'm currently testing Memcached in a Windows machine and we are planning to use it in production while Microsoft Velocity is still in CTP.  It is running well so I believe that Memcached for Windows will do well when our site is already in production.  I'm reading some blogs pertaining to this issue and some of them just mentioned that it must not yet be used in production.
If there are issues, please tell why?  And please, if you have any links about this matter, just post it here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official release of memcached on Windows.  We're working on it right now, but unless you're pulling from a dev branch or you've downloaded a [pre-release](http://labs.northscale.com/memcached-packages/), you've definitely got an unsupported version with a large number of bugs and missing features from the last couple of years.

Comment: I'm using memcached for Win32 which I downloaded from http://jehiah.cz/projects/memcached-win32. It is last updated in 2006. It does it job well. Anyway, we're also trying to use memcached from NorthScale Labs. Thanks

Comment: Is the memcached binary from NorthScale Labs installed as a service?

Comment: It's not just yet.  We are hoping to get it in the normal memcached build infrastructure to ensure it can be supported first.

Comment: The site I mentioned before from where I downloaded the memcached Win32 port I'm using now can be installed as a Windows service.  It is version 1.2.6.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using memcached in production for several years now (since early 2008). We're currently using a 12-instance cluster and it absolutely hums. I would recommend memcached any day of the week.